# Finding range data using month and year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with following attributes

```
lat, lng, month, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5... till y10.
```

Here y1 = data of year 2001, y2 = data of year 2002 same applies to remaining.

I need to fetch the data from month1 and y1 to month2 to y2, 
Ex: from month: March,  year = 2001 to month: August, year 2004
Is it possible to get the data using BETWEEN function? 
How can I write a query to this scenario? Any help would be appreciable!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. And show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lousy, lousy, lousy data format.  This is apparent because you have data spread around columns.  The data should look like:

```
month, year, lat, lng, y
```

So, one row should be 10.  You can do this in Postgres:

```
select t.month, u.ord + 2000 as year, t.lat t.lng, u.y
from t, lateral
     unnest(array[y1, y2, . . .]) with ordinality u(y, ord)
```

Next, you can convert the year/month to a date:

```
select to_date(u.ord + 2000 || '-' || t.month || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as yyyymmdd, t.lat t.lng, u.y
from t, lateral
     unnest(array[y1, y2, . . .]) with ordinality u(y, ord);
```

Now you can use this as a subquery and use `between`:

```
select t.*
from (select to_date(u.ord + 2000 || '-' || t.month || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as yyyymmdd, t.lat t.lng, u.y
      from t, lateral
           unnest(array[y1, y2, . . .]) with ordinality u(y, ord)
     ) t
where yyyymmdd between '2003-04-01'::timestamp and '2005-06-01'::timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know the  data format is not good, Anyway thanks for helping.